# PHP - Selecting directory from dropdown menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, directory, mkdir

I would like to know how to select a directory when the 'Upload' button is selected.

What I'm trying to do is give the user a choice where to upload files, with the option to create a new directory in the selected folder from the drop down menu.

When I try to use `$val` or `$folder` to select the upload directory, nothing is uploaded.

Current code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/FNvteF0i).

This is a screenshot to get a better idea:

[image]

So basically, the user chooses a files(s), chooses the upload destination (with the option to create a new folder in the selected directory), and when the upload button is created, files are uploaded.

Comment: You currently have a form for each section, (file,select folder) you need to incorporate the required fields into one `<form/>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend that users can create directories. You should rather make virtual directories. Also your code is very vulnerable for [SQL-Injection](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection#PHP) .

But if it's just a small project and not public:

Basically you pass the directory name as a POST parameter just like in a simple form.
Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: When I tried to pass $val to the upload block, it does not upload to the selected directory

Comment: Check Lawrence comment. Upload and directory must be in the same form. Once you passed the value right, use move_uploaded_file, there you can specify the destination folder and file name.

Comment: Doing `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" value="" name="upload[]" multiple>
       <button type="submit">Upload!</button>

    <select name="myDirs">
    <option value=""  selected="selected">Select a folder</option>
   
  
    <text></text>
   
   <input type="submit" value="Create">
  </form>` outputs the folders outside of the dropdown menu :S